# defining a subclass constructor

Tags: java, subclass

I've started getting back to java and I have a general question about defining a constructor for an object:
I'm following a tutorial where he defines a HashSet object by the following statement:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

(list is a List object)

And I was wondering what's the difference if I use this statement:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: This is not subclass, this is interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to one of most important concepts of oops, i.e. polymorphism. If you use `HashSet` in place of set then you will not be able to build flexible code. Say, if you want to pass the object as an argument to a method then if you use `Set` interface someday you can pass another implementation like `TreeSet` and the method will work properly. This makes the code loosely coupled.

Answer (score 0):

One of the defining characteristics of the Java Collections Framework is that it is an **interface-based type system**.  The API is defined largely through interfaces that may extend other interfaces.  The base interface is `Collection`.

In this way, most of the collection implementations (eg. `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, etc.) are also assignable to variables or parameters of type `Collection`).  This provides a lot of expressive power to the Framework.

Most of the Java Collection Framework implementations have a constructor that accepts a parameter of type `Collection`.  This is called the "conversion constructor" because it allows you to pass in any collection in the framework whose type extends the `Collection` interface (and most do) and get that collection represented as a collection of the newly constructed type.

In other words:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" });
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
```

The variable `set1` will end up containing a reference to a `HashSet` instance containing all the objects that are also in the `List` instance `list1`.  The conversion constructor, in effect, converted the representation of your data from a List to a HashSet.

Whenever possible, it is typically a best practice to use an object's interface as its type rather than its implementation type.  This gives you much greater flexibility.  Therefore "List myList = ..." is preferred over "ArrayList myList = ...".